# return tuple into strings and why is it only returning the 1st index of list of tuple?

Tags: python

how can I include all in list of tuple?

```
def convert(list_tup):
    for a,b,c in list_tup:
        return c + ' ' + a + ' ' + b

strings = [('w', 'x','2'), ('y', 'z', '3')]
print(convert(strings))
```

output is: `2 w x`
it only returns the 1st index of list of tuple

it is the expected output when i use `print(c + ' ' + a + ' ' + b)`

expected output:

```
2 w x 
3 y z
```

also is there a way i can separate the string without using a string space in return `c + ' ' + a + ' ' + b`
like sep = `' '`

Comment: You are `return`ing from your function after the first iteration. It's not clear what you want to return from the function. A string with each line separated by a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a `return` inside a loop and expect it to return values repeatedly -- once it returns the first value the function is finished.  But if you are trying to generate a sequence of values, you could easily turn it into [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function by using `yield` instead of `return`.  Then when you call your function you get an object which you can iterate over to get the sequence of values.  For example:

```
def convert(list_tup):
    for a,b,c in list_tup:
        yield c + ' ' + a + ' ' + b

strings = [('w', 'x','2'), ('y', 'z', '3')]
for s in convert(strings):
    print(s)
```

gives

```
2 w x
3 y z
```

Or for example, you could use `list` to iterate over these values and put them into a list:

```
print(list(convert(strings)))
```

```
['2 w x', '3 y z']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how:

```
def convert(list_tup):
    
    return '\n'.join([' '.join((tup[-1],)+tup[:-1]) for tup in list_tup])

strings = [('w','x','2'), ('y', 'z', '3')]

print(convert(strings))
```

Output:

```
2 w x
3 y z
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting only "2 w x" is because you have a return statement in the for loop. In the first iteration itself, it returns from the function.

You can directly include a print inside the for loop. Also, instead of `' '`, you can use commas (,)

```
def convert(list_tup):
    for a,b,c in list_tup:
        print(c, a, b)

strings = [('w', 'x','2'), ('y', 'z', '3')]
convert(strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of this line:

```py
return c + ' ' + a + ' ' + b
```

You are causing the function to `return` after the first `iteration`.

You could use a `list comprehension` combined with `f strings` to do what I think you want.

Try this:

```py
def convert(list_tup):
    return [f'{c} {a} {b}' for a,b,c in list_tup]

strings = [('w', 'x', '2'), ('y', 'z', '3')]

for string in convert(strings):
    print(string)
```